# OS-Prober won't find Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I was using a cracked Windows7 copy that came pre-installed with my assembled PC.
Installed Ubuntu 16.04 on one of the two harddisks while Windows 7 was intact on the other.

I havent been able to boot into windows 7 whatsoever.
Can't even use the boot-order to boot as the windows 7 shows some DHCP, PX0E stuff.

Here's the relevant sudo fdisk -l results.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 149.1 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 83FA66EA-A765-45FC-B7F6-86DC2264BFA7

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 304295935 303245312 144.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  304295936 312580095   8284160     4G Linux swap


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9b74d7a5

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1             2048     206847     204800  100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2           206848  293799935  293593088  140G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3        293799936 1910671453 1616871518  771G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb4       1910673406 1953519111   42845706 20.4G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5  *    1910673408 1953519111   42845704 20.4G ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: Welcome tyo askuubuntu! Please [edit] your post to include the output of `sudoi fdisk -l`which will show us the partition layout of your drives. This info is likely to help us determine what went wrong and what you need to do. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek, updated.

Comment: I believe your answer is available [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) although this may seem the flip side of  your situation the basic steps to resolve the problem are the same. If that doesn't resolve your issue please [edit] your question to include what you tried and what happened when you did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ugghh I feel your pain.
I think you may need to reinstall grub. Try creating a live disk/usb first. Make sure you can boot it. Then follow these instructions.
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd